.Net MAUI Mobile App Build Errors : Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
I am getting some strange build errors while I am rebuilidng the.NET MAUI mobile app solution. It worked fine till yesterday.All of sudden I am getting some strange errors now.I deleted .obj & bin folders and restrtaing visual studio & System multiple times but no use.
Here I am sharing the error screenshot for the refrence.

This is one of those error types.
*Dupicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute.
Could you please help me on this. I am unable to proceed with the MAUI build process now.
Thanks in advance.

Check your project (double Click on it) and *.manifest (Android\iOS\Windows) files there is a duplicate, or post them to identify the issue
